# I want Users PC Downloads Path Dynamically

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

```
$zip->extractTo(getenv('HOMEDRIVE').getenv('HOMEPATH').'\Downloads');
```

I use this path to extract files but it create `Downloads` folder on server and store file in it. I want to extract files in my PC downloads

Comment: PHP runs on the server - it cannot access the local filesystem of the user who is using the website. You would need to pass the ZIP file to the user for download, and then it's up to the user whether they a) accept the download, and b) choose to unzip the file. Your site cannot control the user's machine or disk automatically - imagine the security implications if that were possible!!

Comment: That's because PHP runs on the server, not on the browser. If there was a technology that allowed web sites to have direct access to your local files, your computer would already be full of malware and your personal stuff would be on sale in the dark web.